# change style (using variable)

Tags: android

I've this code and I need to change MyCustonTheme1 to 2 or 3 or 4 (From a value by sharedpreferences, user choose a value (1,2,3,4)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyCustomTheme1);
```

In MainActivity I've:

```
if (fade == 500){
            animazione = "R.style.MyCustomTheme1";
        }
        if (fade == 1000){
            animazione = "R.style.MyCustomTheme2";
        }
            [...]
```

Now, I need put "animazione" like this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, animazione);
```

The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity, String) is undefined

Is it possibile change R.style.MyCustomTheme1 to variable like "animazione"?

thanks!

Comment: Let me be clear, there is **no** way to build a themed `AlertDialog` until _Android 3.0_, unless you code it yourself from scratch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note: use of this function is discouraged.** It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

If you need to look up Android resources *by name* (e.g., String -> int conversion), use [`getIdentifier(String, String, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

The first parameter is the resource name *as a string*. The second parameter is the resource type *as a string* (e.g., `"id"` to look in `R.id`, or `"drawable"` to look in `R.drawable`). The third parameter is the package name.

So, theoretically, you should be able to look up a style resource like this:

```
int style = getResources().getIdentifier("MyCustomTheme1", "style", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks. This runs also android < 3?

Comment: @PolHallen Yes, this String-to-int conversion is available as of API Level 1 (all versions). Of course you still need Android 3.0+ to apply the custom style to a dialog.

Comment: @quietmint: this does not work for me, it always returns 0, I have a style defined as "MyApp.Gradient" for which context.getResources().getIdentifier("MyApp_Gradient", "style", context.getPackageName())

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. But you are doing it wrong, you should use

```
int animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme1; // look, no quotes!

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, animazione);
```

Note that the overload taking a *theme identifier* was added in *API level 11*, so it will only work in *Android 3.0* and later.

Comment: +1, totally forgot that it is only available from API level 11+

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the style of the `AlertDialog.Builder` then you'll have to pass in a context and the style. The style is a int, but you are passing in a string. Change it to this:

```
int animazione; // change it to an int

if (fade == 500){
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme1;
        }
else if (fade == 1000){ // also add an 'else' in here (else if)
            animazione = R.style.MyCustomTheme2;
        }
            [...]

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, animazione);
```

Like k-ballo already pointed out this is only available from API level 11+.